# How to get the value only from the Hashtable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

If I have a hastable `$states = @{ 1 = 15; 2 = 5; 3 = 41 }`, The result shows

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
3                              41
2                              5
1                              15
```

I used `$states.GetEnumerator() | sort value -Descending | select -Last 1` to find the minimum value that I need.

The result is:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              5
```

However, I cannot use the value (5) as a new variable to do a calculation. This is due to the result cotains both `name` and `value`. Is there any method to get the minimum value only from the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.Values` property from the beginning:

```
$states.Values | Sort-Object -Descending | Select-Object -Last 1
```

Or expand the `.Value` property:

```
$states.GetEnumerator() | sort value -Descending | select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Value
```